# Devise - redirect user to intervene view after signed up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

When Devise user signs up, I need to redirect him to a view where he can select what kind of user he wants to be, like:

`link_to 'TypeA', new_type_a_path`.

`link_to 'TypeB', new_type_b_path`.

`link_to 'TypeC', new_type_c_path`.

How to configure tis route? I know I can use:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected
    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      signed_in_root_path(resource)
    end
```

But its been a while I worked with RoR, so dont remember - should I create a controller just for this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view, where you place your three links in order the user can choose.

The `after_sign_up_path_for` helper method allows you to specify an URI or a route prefix, so you can create an entry for that view and use it in that method, like:

```
# views/registrations/choices.html.erb
<%= link_to 'TypeA', new_type_a_path %>
<%= link_to 'TypeB', new_type_b_path %>
<%= link_to 'TypeC', new_type_c_path %>

# config/routes.rb
get 'choose', to: 'registrations_controller#choices', as: :choices

# registrations_controller.rb
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  choices_path
end
```